# Ionic Return value navigation on different view

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a form view with an input text. When I click on this input, another view is opened.

In this view, there are an input search and a list. The list change when I change a text from the input search.

I want when I click one item of the list, this view gets closed and the input text change. But I don't know how I can do that.

Can you help me please?

the input text in my form view:

```
<div class="select-typeevent">
    <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ui-sref="menu.setlocation">
        <label class="padding">
            Address:
        </label>
    </ion-item>
</div>
```

My searchview:

```
<ion-view view-title="Address" class="content">
    <ion-content>
        <h1>Address</h1>
        <div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
            <label class="item-input-wrapper">
                <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
                <input class="border-none" name="txtssearch" type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="addresssearch" ng-change="getGeocode(addresssearch)">
            </label>
            <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="addresssearch='';getGeocode(addresssearch)">
                Annuler
            </button>
        </div>
       <div class="list" >
            <a ng-repeat="addr in addresslist" class="item"  ng-click="setaddress(addr)">
                {{addr.address}} {{addr.location}}
            </a>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And the js:

```
    'Use Strict';
angular.module('App').controller('setlocationController', function ($scope,$state, $cordovaOauth, $localStorage, $location, $http, $ionicPopup,$firebaseObject,$ionicHistory, Auth, FURL, Utils) {


    $scope.getGeocode = function (addresssearch) {

        $scope.geodata = {};
        $scope.queryResults = {};
        $scope.queryError = {};

        $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + addresssearch)
          .then(function (_results) {
              $scope.addresslist = [];
              $scope.queryResults = _results.data.results;
              console.log($scope.queryResults);
              $scope.queryResults.forEach(function(result) {
                  $scope.addresslist.push({ 'address': result.formatted_address, 'location': result.geometry.location });
              });

          }, 
           function error(_error){
               $scope.queryError = _error;
           })
    };

    // Here I want when I click one item of the list, this view gets closed and the input text of formview change.
    $scope.setaddress = function (addr) {
    $scope.setaddress = addr;
    $ionicHistory.backView();
}
```

Comment: Please share a bit of the code you have already developped (both JS and HTML)

Comment: tx. I have edit my post. So my problem is in setaddress  function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using an [$ionicModal](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/):

```
$scope.getGeocode = function (addresssearch) {
  ...
  $scope.modal.show();
}
```

Previously set the modal:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
```

Where `my-modal.html` points to the template which shows geocode information.